# List of Dictionary to List of another Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, performance, c#-4.0

I have a huge list of Dictionary like

```
List<Dictionary<String,SomeType>> Dict = new List<Dictionary<string,SomeType>>();
```

I need to convert to the list of dictionary of some other type like below:

```
List<Dictionary<String,SomeOtherType>> AnotherDict;
```

Is there a better approach than foreach on the 'Dict' List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use LINQ:

```
AnotherDict = Dict.Select(d => d.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                              pair => Convert(pair.Value)))
                  .ToList();
```

Where `Convert` is whatever conversion you want to apply to `SomeType` to construct a `SomeOtherType`.

EDIT: As noted in comments, this is no more efficient than using nested `foreach` loops yourselves. It's just simpler.

Comment: Worth mentioning that If performance is the issue, it won't be faster then a simple for loop...just cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can't `ConvertAll()` be a better candidate for this?

Comment: @Bhushan: That would work, certainly - but I personally prefer to stick to just LINQ. It won't make much difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought there is some reason behind you doing it this way...thanks for clearing my doubt..